# What is the purpose of tetrazole in oligonucleotide synthesis?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, biochemistry

The [ATDBio book on nucleic acids](https://www.atdbio.com/content/17/Solid-phase-oligonucleotide-synthesis) describes tetrazole as an activator required to couple nucleotides.

> The diisopropylamino group of the nucleoside phosphoramidite is protonated by the activator, and is thereby converted to a good leaving group. It is rapidly displaced by attack of the 5′-hydroxyl group of the support-bound nucleoside on its neighbouring phosphorus atom.

[image]

The first molecule in the scheme they provide is clearly already protonated; a second step in which the diisopropyl amino group is replaced by a tetrazole molecule is displayed.

What is the purpose of this step; why doesn't the support bound nucleotide attack the phosphorous, directly? Are the arguments purely kinetic (i.e. sterics and availability)?

Comment: Er no, the first molecule in the scheme is not protonated - it is protonated by the tetrazole. The alcohol will not, on its own, displace the di-isopropylamino group from the phosphorus centre.

Comment: In the image in the question, the leftmost amine is already drawn in its protonated form as $\ce{HNR3+}$ and is nucleophilically substituted for tetrazole, no?

Comment: The language here is not quite clear. That is a substitution and there is a nucleophile involved, but the arrow-pushing shown for step 1 (or step 2, for that matter) are almost certainly not what mechanistically happens in this process. Phosphorus compound do not under $S_{\mathrm{N}}2$ reactions normally; they undergo addition-elimination-type substitutions.

Comment: @jacob No, it is shown as protonated by the tetrazole

Comment: @Waylander, it may well have been protonated by tetrazole but what I’m trying to say is that this is not shown as an individual step *in the diagram*. The non-protonated form is never represented diagrammatically. Regardless, that’s really not the point of the question.

Comment: Each step of catalysed reaction is much easier then uncatalysed, because activation energy is lower. Your tetrazole is both better nucleophile then alcohol _and_ leaving group then amine.